# System.Reflection no methods

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I'm trying to enumerate all methods in an assembly and add them to nodes in a treeview:

```
    private void bOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            return;

        var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(ofd.FileName);
        foreach (Module module in asm.GetModules())
        {
            var tnode = new TreeNode(module.Name);
            foreach (MethodInfo method in module.GetMethods())
            {
                tnode.Nodes.Add(method.Name);
            }
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(tnode);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that no methods come under any the modules. I know it's nothing to do with treeview since module.GetMethods().Length returns 0. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You may be interested in http://code.google.com/p/fseye/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the methods in the *modules* in the assembly, rather than in the *types* in the assembly. Change your loop to:

```
foreach (Type type in asm.GetTypes())
{
    var tnode = new TreeNode(type.Name);
    foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods())
    {
        tnode.Nodes.Add(method.Name);
    }
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(tnode);
}
```